# SQSListener not consuming messages from queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I cannot see the messages in the SQS queue being consumed by the @SqsListener

```
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener; //others

@Component
public class Consumer{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

  @SqsListener(value = "TEST-MY-QUEUE")
  public void receiveMessage(String stringJson)  {
    System.out.println("***Consuming message: " + stringJson);
    logger.info("Consuming message: " + stringJson);
  }
```

}

My configuration (Here I print the client queues, and I can deffo spot the queue I want to consume - TEST-MY-QUEUE . It prints the URL correctly in the region. I am also able to see the region loaded correctly (same as queue) in regionProvider

```
@Configuration

public class AwsConfiguration { 

  @Bean
  @Primary
  AmazonSQSAsync sqsClient() {
    AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    System.out.println("Client queues = " + amazonSQSAsync.listQueues()); //The queue I want to consume is here
    return amazonSQSAsync;
  }

  @Bean
  AwsRegionProvider regionProvider() {
    DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain defaultAwsRegionProviderChain = new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain();
    System.out.println("Region = " + defaultAwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion());
    return defaultAwsRegionProviderChain;
  }

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync, QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler) {
    
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(queueMessageHandler);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
  }

  @Bean
  public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
    return queueMessageHandler;
  }

  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }
```

And pom.xml (Java 11, spring boot, spring cloud aws)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I noticed very similar issues in the questions here and I changed my dependencies in pom.xml to be spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging but didnt fix for me. I double checked the names (queue, annotation) all seems fine
When I run my app, starts fine but I dont see any logs or exception. Not one message consumed.
What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end it was an issue with the config (using the credentials)

In application.yml

```
credentials:
  useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain: true #Will use credentials in /.aws
```

And then in the AWSConfig class where you create the AmazonSQSAsync, just make it use that config

```
public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
  DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
  return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
            .withCredentials(defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a third party API. To use invoke Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) from a Java project, use the Official **AWS SDK for Java V2**. If you are not aware how to use this SDK, see this DEV Guide:

[Developer guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

For AWS SQS specific information, see:

[Working with Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-sqs.html)

This has links to AWS Github where you will find POM dependencies, code, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing to this doc. I can see its a complete different approach (using ReceiveMessageRequest class for example). Does it mean this third party API and SQSListener no longer work?

Comment: Amazon recommends the use of AWS SDK for Java V2.

Comment: I see. Its only that I need to consume those messages via listener (as they come). I couldnt find listener related to the guide. Only programatic way to consume the messages...